# scala - swapping first 2 elements in a List

Tags: scala

I'm trying to swap first 2 elements in a List using the below function.

```
  def swap_list(a:List[Int]):List[Int]={
    a match {
      case x::y::Nil => List(y,x)
      case List(x,y,rest @ _*) =>  List(y,x)
      case _ => a
    }
  }

  swap_list(List(10,20,30))
```

This works. However, If I try to include the `rest` I'm getting a error like

```
case List(x,y,rest @ _*) =>  List(y,x) +: rest
```

Error below

```
Error:(27, 50) type mismatch;
found   : Seq[Any]
required: List[Int]
case List(x,y,rest @ _*) =>  List(y,x) +: rest
```

when I'm specifying the function result type in the definition, why am I getting Seq[Any] in the error message?

I need to return List(20,10,30). How to resolve this?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently operators in scala `List` are confusing. You need to concat lists using `++`,

```
def swap_list(a:List[Int]):List[Int]={
  a match {
    case x::y::Nil => List(y,x)
    case List(x,y,rest @ _*) =>  List(y,x) ++ rest
    case _ => a
  }
}

val newList = swap_list(List(10, 20, 30))

println(newList) //List(20, 10, 30)
```

**Summary of `List` operators,**

**1) prepend on `List` using `+:` or `::`**

```
scala> 1000 +: List(1, 2, 3)
res1: List[Int] = List(1000, 1, 2, 3)

scala> 1000 :: List(1, 2, 3)
res4: List[Int] = List(1000, 1, 2, 3)
```

**2) append on `List` using `:+`**

```
scala> List(1, 2, 3) :+ 100
res2: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 100)
```

**3) concat Lists using `++`**, same as [in haskell](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html)

```
scala> List(1, 2, 3) ++ List(4, 5, 6)
res3: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

Comment: when I removed the return type in the function in my code posted, it worked, but the result was ````List(List(20, 10), 30)````. can you explain this?

Comment: which means you are prepending `List(20, 10) +: List(30)` which returns `List[Any]` which is not good. use `++` to concat lists instead see example above

Answer (score 5):

Well, while prayagupd solution works, and clearly explains the problem *(and should be the accepted answer IMHO)*.

I think is worth sharing a *"better"* solution to this problem, since concatenating lists is expensive, it is better to just prepend elements to them.

```
def swapList[T](l: List[T]): List[T] = l match {
  case Nil => Nil
  case x :: Nil => x :: Nil
  case x :: y :: xs => y :: x :: xs
}

swapList(List(10,20,30)) // res0: List[Int] = List(20, 10, 30).
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to `++` instead of `+:` as the latter is for single element.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest implementation is this:

```
def swap_list(a: List[Int]): List[Int] =
  a match {
    case x :: y :: tail => y :: x :: tail
    case _ => a
  }
```